# Why invoice line values not passed in tax line in odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I create a custom field in **account.invoice.line .**

I added the field in account.invoice.tax

I override the prepare invoice function like this

**cost_center_id is Many2one field**

```py
def _prepare_tax_line_vals(self, line, tax):
    res = super(AccountInvoice, self)._prepare_tax_line_vals(line, tax)
    if not res.get('cost_center_id') and line.cost_center_id:
        res['cost_center_id'] = line.cost_center_id.id
    return res
```

I print the cost_center values here the value is printed here.

But in **account.invoice.tax** the values is not there.
How to solve this issue??

Comment: Could you please add your Code?

Comment: This might be issue due to M2M field.

Comment: @CZoellner: I just add the above code in my custom module for pass the account invoice value to account invoice tax.
In odoo default the account_id,taxes,are passed through this function

Comment: @KevalMehta: I use Many2one field here. But I just pass that field in _prepare_tax_line_vals. M2M field not used here